# Invoking a method on the thread that launched the current thread context

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I have a class that launches/terminates a thread using methods called Start/Stop. The Stop method cleans up Threading resources properly but if the thread itself terminates naturally or with an exception, I need to be able to call Stop or another variation (if needed) to clean up properly.

Calling Stop from within the thread method is not an option due to the locking mechanism I have in place.

Is there a way I could Invoke the Stop method in its original context?

```
private bool Terminate { get; set; }
private object _SyncRoot = new object();
private System.Threading.Thread Thread { get; set; }
private System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

public bool Start (ProcessorOptions options)
{
    bool result = false;

    lock (this._SyncRoot)
    {
        if (this.State == EnumState.Ready)
        {
            this.Options = options;

            if (this.CancellationTokenSource != null)
            {
                this.CancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            }

            this.CancellationTokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
            //this.CancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(?, null, true);

            this.Terminate = false;

            this.Thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(this.Process));
            this.Thread.Start();

            result = true;
        }
    }

    return (result);
}

public void Stop ()
{
    lock (this._SyncRoot)
    {
        if (this.State == EnumState.Processing)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Terminate = true;
                this.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel(false);

                if (!this.Thread.Join(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0D)))
                {
                    this.Thread.Abort();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Thread = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Process ()
{
    lock (this._SyncRoot)
    {
        if (this.State != EnumState.Ready)
        {
            throw (new System.InvalidOperationException("The processor instance is not in a ready state."));
        }
    }

    while (!this.Terminate)
    {
        lock (this._SyncRoot)
        {
            if (this.QueuedDocuments.Count == 0)
            {
                if (this.StopAutomaticallyOnQueueEmpty)
                {
                    // Invoke this.Stop() before breaking.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Parallel.For uses CancellationTokenSource here.

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2D));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @Yosi: Added stripped down code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to keep track of your ThreadStates in a separate "maintenance" thread as Mike suggested, you can try this:

Keep the break statement in the Process method to exit the while-loop (and lock context). Add this code at the end of the method:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Stop());
```

This uses the threadpool to invoke the Stop method in your instance as soon as the threadpool has an available thread (usually immediately).

Edit:
You could also add a parameter to your Stop method that signals you only want to clean up resources, and not do any thread synchronization (since the thread is about to exit anyway). Or better, split the existing method in two: Cleanup and Stop. This allows you to invoke Stop (Cleanup) at the end of the Process method without using the thread pool.

Comment: Thanks. Is this how WinForms controls handle the Invoke method internally as well?

Comment: No, the threadpool just run the method on some random thread, Invoke guarantees that you run the method on the GUI thread. I found this article describing the (ugly) details: http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer in your main class that checks the `ThreadState` of each thread that it's managing.  If the state is `ThreadState.Stopped`, go ahead and clean it up (and remove it from the collection of threads to watch).

Comment: A timer? Launch another child thread to manage the first child thread?

Comment: If you have a loop in your main class that's waiting on child threads to finish, you could instead call `if (worker.Thread.Join(0)) worker.Stop();`

Comment: Eventually, I'll just give up and downvote every answer like this on multithreading that suggests polling :((

Comment: And yet, you don't offer up an alternative.

Comment: @MikeVanVertloo because, after threee decades, I can't be bothered any more.